# How to create broken pipe IO exception in java

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I am trying to understand broken pipe exception and thought it would be a good idea to generate one but unfortunately i have not been able to.

Server - netcat
Client - Java socket

```
Server ------------- Client
          <--------- SYN
  SYN,ACK --------->
          <--------- ACK
  FIN,ACK --------->        (when server dies on kill -9)
          <--------- ACK
          <--------- writes some bytes          
  RST ------------->        (no exception thrown at java side)
```

1. why is broken pipe not thrown when writing to a server process that has died?

Answer (score 0):

A pipe is a data stream, typically data being read from a file or from a network socket. A broken pipe occurs when this pipe is suddenly closed from the other end. For a flie, this could be if the file is mounted on a disc or a remote network which has become disconnected. For a network socket, it could be if the network gets unplugged or the process on the other end crashes.

Try reading a big file and while client is reading it, take it out of the network by unplugging the network cable or disabling the network adapter.

or

Simply shutdown the server.

Make sure client is reading a big byte stream from the server so that you can manually do either of the above steps.

Comment: if the network goes away, then you get a read timeout at the reading process. if the process goes away, the OS of writing process will still send a FIN so you get EOF. I cant reproduce broken pipe with the scenarios you have described. do you know the exact piece of source code that throws this exception?